# How do I add .jpg image to correspond with list items?

Tags: java, arrays, list, jpeg

I have my program displaying a random restaurant when a radio button is selected. What I'm wanting to do now is have an image of the restaurants logo show up underneath the text that shows up when the radio button is selected. Im really just not sure what I need to do or where I need to look for information on how to achieve this. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

```js
import TrySource.TryWindow;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TrySomethingNew extends JFrame
{

  // Radio buttons for selecting colors
  private JRadioButton jrbMexican, jrbItalian;
        JLabel jlblResult; 

  // Declare a panel for displaying message
  private TryWindow TryWindow;
  
  //textarea for result
  private JLabel jlblRestaurantName; 


  // Main method
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    TrySomethingNew frame = new TrySomethingNew();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setTitle("Try Something New");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

  public TrySomethingNew() 
  {
    // Create a MovingMessageCanvas instance and set colors
    TryWindow = new TryWindow("Let's try this.");
    TryWindow.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    // Panel to hold radio buttons
    JPanel jpRadioButtons = new JPanel();
    jpRadioButtons.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder("Select A Food Genre"));
    jpRadioButtons.add(jrbMexican = new JRadioButton("Mexican"));
    jpRadioButtons.add(jrbItalian = new JRadioButton("Italian"));


    // Group radio buttons
    ButtonGroup btg = new ButtonGroup();
    btg.add(jrbMexican);
    btg.add(jrbItalian);
    
    //Panel to hold result
    JPanel jpResultPanel = new JPanel();
    jpResultPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder("Result"));    

    // Place panels in the frame
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(jpRadioButtons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jpResultPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    

    // Register listeners with the buttons

    jrbMexican.addItemListener(new EventListener());
    jrbItalian.addItemListener(new EventListener());
    
    jlblRestaurantName = new JLabel();
    jpResultPanel.add(jlblRestaurantName);
    jlblRestaurantName.setVisible(true);
 
    
  }//end main

  // Handle radio button selections
  class EventListener implements ItemListener 
  {
      
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
      if (jrbMexican.isSelected())
      {
        java.util.List<String> mexicanList = Arrays.asList(
        "<html>Jose Locos<br>853 N Glenstone Ave, Springfield, MO 65802<br>(417) 831-1300<html>",
        "<html>Amigos Mexican Restaurant<br>2118 S Campbell Ave, Springfield, MO 65807<br>(417) 887-1401<html>");
        
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        String random = mexicanList.get(randomizer.nextInt(mexicanList.size()));
        jlblRestaurantName.setText(random);
        
        
      }//end if jrbMexican isSelected
      
      if (jrbItalian.isSelected())
      {
        java.util.List<String> italianList = Arrays.asList(
        "<html>Zios Italian Kitchen<br>1249 E Kingsley St, Springfield, MO 65804<br>(417) 889-1919<html>",
        "<html>Bambinos Cafe<br>1141 E Delmar St, Springfield, MO 65807<br>(417) 862-9999<html>");
        
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        String random = italianList.get(randomizer.nextInt(italianList.size()));
        jlblRestaurantName.setText(random);
        
      }//end if jrbItalian isSelected
    }//end itemStateChanged
  }//end eventListener
}//end TrySomethingNew
```

```js
package TrySource;

// TryWindow.java: Display a message on a JPanel
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TryWindow extends JPanel 
{
  /** The message to be displayed */
  private String message = "Try Something New";

  /** The x coordinate where the message is displayed */
  private int xCoordinate = 465;

  /** The y coordinate where the message is displayed */
  private int yCoordinate = 40;

  /** Indicate whether the message is displayed in the center */
  private boolean centered;

  /** The interval for moving the message horizontally and vertically */
  private int interval = 10;

  /** Default constructor */
  public TryWindow() 
  {
      
  }

  /** Constructor with a message parameter */
  public TryWindow(String message) 
  {
    this.message = message;
  }

  /** Return message */
  public String getMessage() 
  {
    return message;
  }

  /** Set a new message */
  public void setMessage(String message) 
  {
    this.message = message;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return xCoordinator */
  public int getXCoordinate() 
  {
    return xCoordinate;
  }

  /** Set a new xCoordinator */
  public void setXCoordinate(int x) 
  {
    this.xCoordinate = x;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return yCoordinator */
  public int getYCoordinate() 
  {
    return yCoordinate;
  }

  /** Set a new yCoordinator */
  public void setYCoordinate(int y) 
  {
    this.yCoordinate = y;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return centered */
  public boolean isCentered() 
  {
    return centered;
  }

  /** Set a new centered */
  public void setCentered(boolean centered) 
  {
    this.centered = centered;
    repaint();
  }

  /** Return interval */
  public int getInterval() 
  {
    return interval;
  }

  /** Set a new interval */
  public void setInterval(int interval) 
  {
    this.interval = interval;
    repaint();
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (centered) 
    {
      // Get font metrics for the current font
      FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

      // Find the center location to display
      int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message);
      int stringAscent = fm.getAscent();
      // Get the position of the leftmost character in the baseline
      xCoordinate = getWidth() / 2 - stringWidth / 2;
      yCoordinate = getHeight() / 2 + stringAscent / 2;
    }

    g.drawString(message, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
  }

  }
```

Comment: `logo show up underneath the text ` What did you use to show up your text? JLabel? JTextField?

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a model class to hold the information about a restaurant.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Image;

public class Restaurant {

    private final Image image;

    private final RestaurantType restaurantType;

    private final String name;
    private final String address;
    private final String phoneNumber;

    public Restaurant(Image image, RestaurantType restaurantType, String name,
            String address, String phoneNumber) {
        this.image = image;
        this.restaurantType = restaurantType;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public RestaurantType getRestaurantType() {
        return restaurantType;
    }

    public enum RestaurantType {
        MEXICAN, ITALIAN
    }

}
```

Next, you modify your code to use the Restaurant class.

Define a List of Restaurants.

```
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();
```

Next, add your restaurant information.

```
    Restaurant restaurant1 = new Restaurant(image, RestaurantType.MEXICAN, 
            "Jose Locos", "853 N Glenstone Ave, Springfield, MO 65802",
            "(417) 831-1300");
    restaurants.add(restaurant1);
    ...
```

Finally, modify your itemStateChanged method to use the Restaurant List.

You'll have to read the images from your Java project.  Here's one way to do that.

```
private Image getImage(String fileName) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Put the images in the same directory as the Java source code.  That way, you pass the name of the file to the getImage method.  No path strings are needed.

Read all the images before you construct the GUI.  You only need to read the images one time.